# Cucumber rake cucumber:ok - errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, gherkin

I am getting errors when I run: rake cucumber:ok 
Can you please tell me how to fix the following error?

Gem versions I am using:

```
rails Rails 3.0.8.rc4
rspec 2.6.3
cucumber 0.10.3
```

Errors when I run: `rake cucumber:ok`

```
[ticketee (master)]$ rake cucumber:ok
/Users/duser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber --profile default
Using the default profile...
features/creating_projects.feature: Lexing error on line 12: '%%_FEATURE_END_%%'. See http://wiki.github.com/cucumber/gherkin/lexingerror for more information. (Gherkin::Lexer::LexingError)
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/gherkin-2.3.10/lib/gherkin/lexer/i18n_lexer.rb:23:in `scan'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/gherkin-2.3.10/lib/gherkin/lexer/i18n_lexer.rb:23:in `scan'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/gherkin-2.3.10/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:31:in `parse'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-0.10.3/lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:37:in `parse'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-0.10.3/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:28:in `block in load'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-0.10.3/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:26:in `each'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-0.10.3/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:26:in `load'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-0.10.3/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:14:in `features'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-0.10.3/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:132:in `features'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-0.10.3/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:45:in `run!'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-0.10.3/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-0.10.3/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-0.10.3/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/Users/duser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/duser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p18...]

Tasks: TOP => cucumber:ok
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
[ticketee (master)]$
```

Contents of features/creating_projects.feature

```
Feature: Creating projects 
In order to have projects to assign tickets to 
As a user I want to create them easily 
Scenarios: Creating a project 
  Given I am on the homepage 
  When I follow "New Project" 
  And I fill in "Name" with "Text Mate 2" 
  And I press "Create Project" 
  Then I should see "Project has been created"
```

I figured out the problem:

> In the features/creating_projects.feature file, I had "Scenarios:", and it should be "Scenario:". This is the reason for the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [lexing error](https://github.com/cucumber-attic/gherkin2/wiki/LexingError) on line 12 of features/creating_projects.feature and its most likely at the end of the feature definition. Are you using the correct syntax in the file?

Comment: I have only 11 lines in features/creating_projects.feature<br /> Feature: Creating projects
  In order to have projects to assign tickets to
  As a user
  I want to create them easily
  
  Scenarios: Creating a project
    Given I am on the homepage
    When I follow "New Project"
    And I fill in "Name" with "Text Mate 2"
    And I press "Create Project"
    Then I should see "Project has been created"

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I didnt know how to post with out the format messing up.

Comment: No problem, I seem to be missing a few lines in the cucumber file though. Care to fill that in?

Comment: I figured out the problem. In the features/creating_projects.feature file, its "Scenario:" and I was using "Scenarios:" instead. This is the reason for the errors.